# Perforce commit from setted user

Tags: bash, perforce

When I do submit through p4 I want to set user (not logged user) for commit.
Can anybody help me or commit makes only from logged user ?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set  the [P4USER](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4USER.html) environmental variable. In `bash`, this can be done using  the `export` command.

```
export P4USER=MyAlterEgo
```

Another is to use `p4 -u <username> <command>`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can commit from a user for whom you do not have a valid ticket is dependent on your security settings.  If you have passwords, you'll have to either have a password or ticket to perform an operation as that user.  However, if you have an unauthenticated repository, you can use the `P4USER` environment variable or the `-u` switch on the command line (or even a `.p4config` file) to set your user to an arbitrary user.

For authenticated systems and users, you'll need to be logged in as that user, but perforce doesn't require that you be logged in as only one user at a time.   Because `p4 login` issues tickets and multiple tickets can be outstanding to the same unix user, you can use the `p4 login` command to log in as multiple users and then use either the `P4USER` environment variable or the `-u` switch to perform operations as any of those users.

For example (bash assumed):

```
> p4 login userA
Password: <enter userA's password>
userA logged in
> p4 login userB
Password: <enter userB's password>
userB logged in
> P4USER=userA p4 login -s
User userA ticket expires in 9 hours 59 minutes.
> p4 -u userB login -s
User userB ticket expires in 9 hours 59 minutes.
```

Any other command can be executed either of those ways, as long as the tickets are still valid.